# C Why won't my program loop and "if-statements" not work?

Tags: c++, c, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I am trying to write a code for school that allows the user to calculate different salaries based on the type of employee it is working. I believe I have all of the math coding done correctly however I need to make the program loop after each employee is selected. Here is the coding that I have completed thus far:

```
int paycode = 0;                                        
double manager_salary;                                  
double worker_salary;                                   
double worker_hours;                                    
double ot;                                              
double worker_wage;                                     
double sales;                                           
double commission;                                      
double pieces;                                          
double piece_wage;                                      
double pieceworker;                                     

while (paycode >= 0 && paycode != 1)                    
{
    printf("\n Enter the employee paycode (1-4) (-1 to end): ");        
    scanf_s("%d", &paycode);

    if (paycode = 1)                                                    
    {
        printf("\n Manager Selected");                                  
        printf("\n Enter weekly Salary: ");                             
        scanf_s("%lf", &manager_salary);
        printf("\nManagers Pay is $%.2f", manager_salary);              
    }
    else if (paycode = 2)
    {
        printf("\n Hourly Worker Selected");                            
        printf("\n Enter the hourly salary: ");                         
        scanf_s("%lf", &worker_salary);
        printf("\n Enter the total hours worked: ");                    
        scanf_s("%lf", &worker_hours);
        if (worker_hours > 40.00)                                               
            ot = (worker_hours - 40.00) * worker_salary *1.5;                   
        else
            ot = 0.00;                                                          
        if (worker_hours > 40.00)                                               
            worker_wage = 40 * 16.78 + ot;                                      
        else
            worker_wage = worker_hours * worker_salary;                         
        printf("\n Hourly Worker's Pay is $%.2f", worker_wage);                 
    }
    else if (paycode = 3)
    {
        printf("\n Commission Worker Selected");                        
        printf("\n Enter gross weekly sales: ");                        
        scanf_s("%lf", &sales);
        commission = sales * .057 + 250;                                
        printf("\n Commission Worker's Pay is $%.2f", commission);      
    }
    else if (paycode = 4)
    {
        printf("\n Pieceworker Selected");                              
        printf("\n Enter number of pieces: ");                          
        scanf_s("%lf", &pieces);
        printf("\n Enter wage per piece: ");                            
        scanf_s("%lf", &piece_wage);
        pieceworker = pieces * piece_wage;
        printf("\n Pieceworker's pay is $%.2f", pieceworker);           
    }
}
return 0;
```

}

When I run the program the if statements don't work and the program just spits out every single printf statement I have written.

Please help me in telling me how to get my if statements to work and how to properly make a loop when properly filling out an employee salary.

TIA

Comment: Pop quiz: what does `=` do? What does `==` do? When should you use one, or the other? Are you using them correctly? (Cheat sheet: the answer to the last one is "no") Bonus question: [do you know the person who asked his question just before you did yours?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50263460/c-function-not-receiving-return-value)

Comment: Sadly `=` != `==`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Ever get the feeling you are repeating yourself?

Comment: It's a thankless task, but someone has to do it...

Comment: *repetitio est mater studiorum*

Comment: Turn on all warnings (`-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic`), read and fix them. This typo could have been avoided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your if statements needs to have '==' instead of '='. Do the changes and try it out, if statements will start working.

Comment: Additionally you should look to use switch case instead of if and break down your code into small chunks (functions)

Comment: Recommend an edit to the answer to move that comment into it. It's a worthwhile addition.

Comment: Don't waste time answering trivial typo questions. Just flag the question for closing.

Comment: Thanks a million! I can't believe I overlooked this simple fix... I will look more carefully at my coding from now on.

Answer (score 1):

use `==` instead of `=`
for example

```
if (paycode == 1)
{
}
```

Comment: Don't waste time answering trivial typo questions. Just flag them for closing.